# Comprehensive list of NER labeling schemes with pros/cons

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, named-entity-recognition, annotation

Are there any reference document(s) that give a comprehensive list of NER labeling schemes (e.g., IOB1, IOB2, or IOBES) along with their pros/cons, and ideally some pointers to publications? I am mostly interested in how the choice of the labeling schemes impacts machine learning algorithms' performances.

Answer (score 1):

About the BIO or BIESO scheme, see http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/papers/RatinovRo09.pdf